# Exclude Generated Groovy Setters and Getters in JaCoCo Code Coverage

Tags: java, groovy, testng, jacoco

How to exclude generated groovy setters and getters method in Jacoco with maven in pom.xml?
I Use 0.8.5 Jacoco version, but I never found a way not to include the setter and getter methods generated by groovy in Jacoco's report. I'm still new to using Jacoco and thank you in advance for your help
P.S. Tests written using testng

Comment: Can you share the relevant pom.xml snippets?

Comment: Object has only Getters & Setters, if you dont want to cover, just exclude all the package.
Use <excludes> tag in pom.xml config